# Firebase planned notification using Database

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-realtime-database

My application is progressing very nicely. But I dont know what to do here. I want to push notification. I want to send the information in the database. I want to increase when process is OK. I want to be in that order with example.

1) A notification will come. "Hello, it's Group1 Words".

2) User will clicks to notification. User can see Words of groupRef=Group1 (Word1,Word2 and Word3's groupRef=Group1)

3) After the user has done some work, the count of groups will increase

4) The last and most important step, The Group1 Words will come at 5 o'clock. and Then will come at 12 o'clock and 11 o'clock after day. Each group will be planned similarly.

I think, I have enough to simulate my problem. I didnt find a way out of this point of the application. Thanks for your help.

[image: My DataBase]

Comment: That sounds like a nice requirement to add to your application. There are quite some steps involved in turning this requirement into working code: handling the clicks, increasing the counters, handling the triggering at specific times, sending the notifications, etc. As it stands now, this is way to broad to answer with any confidence. What specific step of turning the requirement into code is giving you problems?

Comment: Thank you for your attantion Mr. Puffelen. I believe i can handle to 1,2,3th steps. But I dont know how to combine 4th step with other steps. I didnt find any document planned to sending a scheduled notification.

Comment: Scheduling **could** be done with Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#other_examples_of_batch_jobs_in_the_firebase_cloud

Comment: Thanks. I will search